# Get Method in C#

Tags: c#, xrm

I came across C# codes in the following pattern but quite don't get where that `Set` method comes from.

```
// obj is an instance of Microsoft's Xrm Entity class
obj.Set("property_name", property_value);
```

Based on Xrm's Entity class definition, there is no member method called `Set`.

Can someone give me some light on this?

Comment: I suspect `Set` is an extension method.

Comment: Specifically, it looks like an extension method that wraps some reflection calls to manipulate the PropertyInfos on Entity

Answer (score 1):

Since C# 3.0 classes can get extension methods which are not declared in the class itself.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/extension-methods-in-C-Sharp-3-0/

I suspect this is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

if you're in visual studio, you can right click on the `Set` call and click "go to definition"

you can get at least a metadata file of nearly any member of any class you're using that way.

Comment: Hi Sam,  Thank you for your answer.  I already tried but F12 (go to definition) just doesn't work on that code.  That's what puzzled me.  Is that C# feature or something?